# Spring boot oauth callback for google

Tags: java, spring-boot, openid-connect, google-oauth

I am sharing the complete code regards to my problem.
I am taking the social configuration  file handled via social-cfg.xml it is in classpath.

**social-cfg.xml**

```
google.client.id=#####################################################################
google.client.secret=############################
google.scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

I  have made java handler to handle this config file

**socialConfig.java**

```
    package com.inno.config;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
    import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors;
    import org.springframework.social.UserIdSource;
    import org.springframework.social.config.annotation.ConnectionFactoryConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.social.config.annotation.EnableSocial;
    import org.springframework.social.config.annotation.SocialConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionFactoryLocator;
    import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository;
    import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionSignUp;
    import org.springframework.social.connect.UsersConnectionRepository;
    import org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcUsersConnectionRepository;
    import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController;
    import org.springframework.social.google.connect.GoogleConnectionFactory;
    import org.springframework.social.security.AuthenticationNameUserIdSource;

    import com.inno.dao.AppUserDAO;
    import com.inno.service.ConnectionSignUpImpl;
    @Configuration
    @EnableSocial
    // Load to Environment.
    @PropertySource("classpath:social-cfg.properties")
    public class SocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer {


         private boolean autoSignUp = false;

          @Autowired
            private DataSource dataSource;
          @Autowired
            private AppUserDAO appUserDAO;
        @Override
        public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {
             try {
                    this.autoSignUp = Boolean.parseBoolean(env.getProperty("social.auto-signup"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    this.autoSignUp = false;
                }
            // Google
                GoogleConnectionFactory gfactory = new GoogleConnectionFactory(//
                        env.getProperty("google.client.id"), //
                        env.getProperty("google.client.secret"));

                gfactory.setScope(env.getProperty("google.scope"));

                cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(gfactory);
            }
 //............. more code regards to another functionality.
```

when i am hitting this href

```
<a th:href="@{/auth/google}">Google</a>
        <br />
```

Then it's redirecting to google page with error as below

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:8787/auth/google, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/#######?project=#######
```

when i visit  `https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/#######?project=#######`

there are two option's

1. Authorized JavaScript origins
2. Authorized redirect URIs

I have set both of them to validate with my webapp. I just don't where is the point which stuck out this issue. PLease help me out. Also ask for any other requirement if required.

Answer (score 1):

redirect URI in the google developer console must exactly match where you are sending your request from.  In your case the error message tells you exactly where you are sending your request form.

> http://localhost:8787/auth/google

Which means that you need to have that exactly in the Google developer console under Authorized redirect URIs or the authentication sever will not accept your request.

Note Port must be included.  Exactly means exactly with the exception of cased.

Comment: Thanks I just solved the issue by applying it.But now i am having issue that how to get callback to webapp after authorization using Oauth .

Comment: thats what the redirect does it returns the authorization to the location you tell it to.   your telling it to return authorization to http://localhost:8787/auth/google  which i would assume is your webapp